Proxy rejects localhost on Windows Server
I am running Selenium for Python (miniconda) on a Windows 10 VM. When selenium starts up, it starts a server at http://localhost/ . However, it needs to connect to the public internet through a proxy at work. When the packets go out, the proxy cannot resolve http://localhost, and the Selenium fails to initialize. How do I add an exception locally on Windows 10 to bypass the proxy for localhost? Alternatively, what do I need to tell my networking team to modify the organization proxy settings?

check your HOSTS file for any entries involving localhost... sounds like that's being redirected to the proxy.

I have uncommented the line  127.0.0.1       localhost and rebooted. That did not work.
